# Does line mean "segment" here?

Tags: meaning

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/dPzbuEunSLk?t=616) (a video link with a time stamp)

> you can
>   completely line a room with foam

Does line mean "segment" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the meaning is this :

> to cover the inside surface of something

Comment: While this answer might be correct, you should edit your answer to provide a dictionary definition and a link to your reference.